# Where does IntelliJ IDEA store SSH keys for Git?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh

Where does IntelliJ IDEA store SSH keys for Git authentication and how can such storage be cleared?

I performed git fetch in Idea with my ssh key (`~/.ssh/id_ed25519`) against authenticate to git repo not encrypted.

[image: Idea menu > Git > Fetch]

Then I encrypted the key using `ssh-keygen -p -f ~\.ssh\id_ed25519`. Surprisingly the git fetch action invoked from Idea still worked. Even after

- restarting the computer
- restarting Windows native OpenSSH agent
- purging keys from windows native OpenSSH agent by `ssh-add -D`
- restarting Idea with Menu > File > Invalidate Caches ...